# nginx run without sudo or automatically enter password don't need i enter

Tags: linux, nginx

I try ~/nginx/sbin/nginx, get this msg:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-      user privileges, ignored in /home/zxr/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] open() "/home/zxr/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

so can I run nginx without `sudo`?, or automatically enter passwd?

Comment: yes you can run nginx with sudo

Answer (score 0):

If you want nginx to bind port 80, must use super user to run nginx.

You can run nginx without `sudo`, but it can not bind the port below 1024, and make sure the user has the permission to visit the data, for example: `/home/zxr/nginx/logs/`.

Answer (score 0):

I just auto on nginx when i reboot my vps.
sudo $HOME/nginx/sbin/nginx

```
$ sudo update-rc.d nginx default
$ sudo reboot
$ google-chrome http://localhost
```

if u see

Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

it works